# Whi isn't the class member updated on each request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a newbie to JavaScript. I have created a NodeJS server which takes a car number as request parameter and adds the car to a parking lot. The parking lot is a class with an array member as follows.

```
class Parking {
  constructor(size) {
    this.parkingLimit = size;
    this.cars = new Array(size).fill("");
    this.carsParked = 0;
  }

  parkOne(carNumber) {
    let slotNumber;
    // console.log(this.cars);
    if (this.carsParked >= this.parkingLimit) {
      throw new Error("No more Parking space left in Parking Lot");
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < this.parkingLimit; index++) {
      if (this.cars[index] === "") {
        this.cars[index] = carNumber;
        this.carsParked++;
        slotNumber = index;
        break;
      }
    }
    return {
      carNumber: carNumber,
      slotNumber: slotNumber,
    };
  }

  unParkOne(index) {
    if (index < this.parkingLimit && this.cars[index] !== undefined) {
      this.cars.index = "";
      this.carsParked--;
      return index;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new Parking(process.env.PARKING_LOT_SIZE);
```

And the car is added by the following ExpressJS code:

```
const express = require("express");
const Parking = require("./models/parkingModel");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ limit: "10kb" }));

app.get("/:carNumber", (req, res, next) => {
  const carNumber = req.params.carNumber;
  //   console.log(carNumber);
  const result = Parking.parkOne(carNumber);

  res.status(201).json({
    status: "success",
    result: {
      data: result,
    },
  });
});
```

Whenever I hit a get request for the first time, the array is updated with the carNumber at index 0 but for any further time I try to hit the url with a new parameter, the array is never updated. Why does this happen?

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me. Why is your 'P' uppercase in 'Parking' inside the get request? Is that an instance of the class? Can you show the code where you make a Parking object after exporting. It works fine for me.

Comment: @RajathaDH I just updated my code snippet kindly check it.

Comment: @RajathaDH the module automatically exports a new instance of parking with size from process.env.PARKING_LOT_SIZE

Comment: Yes. I just tried out your code. Copied the exact same thing, works fine for me. Can you check your environment variables. You might have set the lot size to a low number. Try setting the value inside the model itself.

Comment: Just a tip to destructure a req you can do const { carNumber } = req.params makes the code alot neater and then if the req contains multiple params you can do const { carNumber, carType, carColor } = req.params